# Add new column to Cosmos DB Json data using azure data factory

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory

we have a requirement to add few columns to the Json data in Cosmos DB, but struggling with the complex data type (Address). Can some one guide me how I can add new column and transform data, as we have huge data(millions of records) to transform.

Here is sample JSON data Request

```json
{
    "id": "108-406-004",
    "Title": "Mr",
    "FirstName": "John",
    "LastName": "Smith",
    "Addresses": [
        {
        "Line1": "5 London Road",
        "Country": "UNITED KINGDOM"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to add new column("Line1LowerCase") to the Address array and set the value as lower(Line1), so the output should be like this:

```json
{
    "id": "108-406-004",
    "Title": "Mr",
    "FirstName": "John",
    "LastName": "Smith",
    "Addresses": [
        {
        "Line1": "5 London Road",
        "Country": "UNITED KINGDOM",
        **"Line1LowerCase": "5 london road"**
        }
    ]
}

Here is what I tried so far, but the Address array is coming like this 
"Addresses": {
        "Line1": [
            "5 London Road"
        ],
        "Country": [
            "UNITED KINGDOM"
        ],
        "Addressline1Internal": "[\"5 london road\"]",
    }
```

Used Data factory to import data from Cosmos db dataset, added the derived column step to transform the json data and Sink the result to Cosmos DB dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to update the ID "108-406-004" to add a new property, you can use a copy activity with the option "Write behaviour" as "Upsert". Using this option will automatically add the new property to the record in Cosmos DB.

[image: Write behaviour]

**Here is how I tested your case:**

1. My cosmos DB had already a record for your first json example (without the property "Line1LowerCase".

[image: before]

2. New copy activity create with the option "Upsert" and without any mapping in the copy activity.

[image: final result]

3. After running the copy activity using the sson with the new property it adds this new property to cosmos automatically:

[image: copy dataset]

Also, there is no mapping in the source and sink datasets:
[image: source dataset]

[image: sink dataset]

Source Code:

```
{
    "name": "pipeline3",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Copy data1",
                "type": "Copy",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "JsonSource",
                        "storeSettings": {
                            "type": "AzureBlobStorageReadSettings",
                            "recursive": true,
                            "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                        },
                        "formatSettings": {
                            "type": "JsonReadSettings"
                        }
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "type": "CosmosDbSqlApiSink",
                        "writeBehavior": "upsert",
                        "disableMetricsCollection": false
                    },
                    "enableStaging": false
                },
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "LandingJson",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                ],
                "outputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "CosmosDbSqlApiCollection1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

**How to transform the value to lowercase**

Data Factory doesn't allow you to transform the property in a copy activity.
For that you can use a Data Flow and then call this data flow from your pipeline.

Here is an example of a Data Flow to replace that simple copy activity:

Source from Json

[image: source]

Select to pull the properties you need

[image: select 1]

Derived Column to transform lowercase

[image: derived]

Alter step to allow upsert

[image: alter]

Sink into Cosmos DB

[image: sink]

Source Code:

```
{
    "name": "dataflow3",
    "properties": {
        "type": "MappingDataFlow",
        "typeProperties": {
            "sources": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "LandingJson",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "SourceJson"
                }
            ],
            "sinks": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "CosmosDbSqlApiCollection1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "SinkCosmos"
                }
            ],
            "transformations": [
                {
                    "name": "Select"
                },
                {
                    "name": "DerivedColumn"
                },
                {
                    "name": "AlterRow"
                }
            ],
            "script": "source(output(\n\t\tid as string,\n\t\tTitle as string,\n\t\tFirstName as string,\n\t\tLastName as string,\n\t\tAddresses as (Line1 as string, Country as string)[]\n\t),\n\tallowSchemaDrift: true,\n\tvalidateSchema: false,\n\tignoreNoFilesFound: false,\n\tdocumentForm: 'arrayOfDocuments') ~> SourceJson\nSourceJson select(mapColumn(\n\t\tid,\n\t\tTitle,\n\t\tFirstName,\n\t\tLastName,\n\t\tLine1 = Addresses[1].Line1\n\t),\n\tskipDuplicateMapInputs: true,\n\tskipDuplicateMapOutputs: true) ~> Select\nSelect derive(Line1LowerCase = lower(Line1)) ~> DerivedColumn\nDerivedColumn alterRow(upsertIf(true())) ~> AlterRow\nAlterRow sink(allowSchemaDrift: true,\n\tvalidateSchema: false,\n\tdeletable:false,\n\tinsertable:false,\n\tupdateable:false,\n\tupsertable:true,\n\tformat: 'document',\n\tskipDuplicateMapInputs: true,\n\tskipDuplicateMapOutputs: true) ~> SinkCosmos"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the input. Could you please provide some details to how I can add new columns via Copy activity, as I can see an option called mapping but when I add the new column, then it says that column is not exists in source and I tried with import schema option and this time it came back with an error saying Sink collection is empty.  I have also tried with flattening the source JSON but it is creating multiple records due to 1 to many relation with Address collection. Is there a way I can convert this flatten JSON to cosmos DB so it saves the Address as array .

Comment: Hi, I 've just added some additional notes, screenshots and source code to my original answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Diego. Much appreciated for helping on this. I am still at lost and please bear with me as I just started looking in to ADF, so may be asking too many questions. With regards to the step 3  (After running the copy activity using the sson with the new property it adds this new property to cosmos automatically: ) , could you please explain how it adds the new property and transformed the data to lower case, as I am reading every where the copy activity doesn't do any transformation as it needs to convert the data to lower case. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I concentrate on the requirement to add the new property and forgot the lowercase requirement.

Comment: Please check the new section "How to transform the value to lowercase" I added to the answer. I hope it works for you.

Comment: Thank you for your input. taking your input, I have added the below flow to get the desired output (Desired column did the trick for me)

Comment: From where can I find the copy activity on portal?